# .htaccess not forwarding requests to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com [L,R=301,NC]

#For api send authorization header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

When I try to post to
https://api.example.com/user/login
it gives me this [image]

Shouldn't it just forward my request to https://www.example.com
I can't figure it out why it won't work.

EDIT:
The problem might be that ssl for https://api.example.com doesn't work

Comment: _“The problem might be that ssl for `https://api.example.com` doesn't work”_ – of course that is the problem. Your browser tries to connect to that URL, and for that to happen successfully, your HTTPS setup needs to be in order. Your rewriting only happens _after_ the browser made a successful HTTPS connection to `https://api.example.com`.

Comment: I got it, thank you